# Splitting a string and executing sub in for loop

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl. I have string like

```
my $http_origin_servers_list = "abc:2220,cde:40111,efg:45643";
```

and I have a sub called like

```
executeCommand($host);
```

I want to convert `$http_origin_servers_list` into array

```
my @values = ("abc:2220", "cde:40111", "efg:45643");
```

and call `executeCommand` with each value in turn like

```
executeCommand("abc:2220");
```

Comment: `executeCommand for split /,/, $http_origin_servers_list`

Comment: @raina77ow means `executeCommand($_) for split /,/, $http_origin_servers_list;`

Comment: Why submit that as a comment, @raina77ow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, you asked for

```
my @hosts = split /,/, $http_origin_servers_list;
for my $host (@hosts) {
    executeCommand($host);
}
```

but you can skip creating the array.

```
for my $host (split /,/, $http_origin_servers_list) {
    executeCommand($host);
}
```

This can be written more tersely if you so desire.

```
executeCommand($_) for split /,/, $http_origin_servers_list;
```

Comment: what if my $http_origin_servers_list=abc:2220 only one element will spilt function convert to array my @values=(abc:2220)

Comment: yes it does thanks I have downloaded perl ide I am enjoying it

Comment: @ikegami ... does looping over the `split( ... )` expression directly reliably avoid creating a temporary array of strings in memory?

Comment: @Gregory Nisbet, First, let me make clear that I wasn't recommending any of the approaches over the others.

Comment: As for your question, yes, the foreach loop will iterate directly over the scalars returned by `split`. The "problem" with assigning the scalars to the array first is that the the scalars need to be copied. This isn't so bad because the string itself isn't copied (because of the TEMP mechanism in older version of Perl, and because of the COW mechanism in newer ones). But it's still a couple of memory allocations per scalar. Once there, though, iterating over an array is quite efficient. Internally, that case is optimized to simply iterate over the indexes.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $http_origin_servers_list = "abc:2220,cde:40111,efg:45643";
my @v = split (/,/, $http_origin_servers_list);
print ("$_\n") for @v; # or executeCommand($_) for @v
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the server list, you can create the list directly:

```
my @servers = qw/abc:1 def:2 ghi:3/;
for my $server (@servers) {
    say $server;
}
```